# Tag Manager Not Firing on Subdomains (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, google-tag-manager

Does anyone have any ideas as to why a GTM trigger won't fire on a subdomain. I can see the subdomain in my GA4 reports so I know it's there but I can't get any tags associated with it to fire. Am I missing something easy?

Tried setting cookieDomain to 'Auto" although I know that's not necessary in GA4. I tried adding a GA4 config tag to fire on subdomain - but that just duplicated hits in tag manager. I can see the subdomain in the GA4 reports, so I know it sees it. I just can't get any event related tags to fire.

Comment: Are there conditions within the tags that is preventing it from firing on the subdomain? Can you provide an example of the firing conditions for a tag that works on the parent domain but no the sub?

Comment: I found a solution that works using the "change history" trigger followed by the hostname "contains" and page URL "contains" for the page I'm trying to track. I am not really familiar with the change history trigger but all my pages are now tracking on the subdomain.

Comment: Change history is used for mobile applications and single page applications where the url fragment (any after #) changes.